# Left input takes all available space

Tags: css, input, html

I know this questions has already been answered before and I've read the topics :

- [Make div take all space left after another div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15487358/make-div-take-all-space-left-after-another-div)
- [Expand div to take remaining width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260122/expand-div-to-take-remaining-width)
- [Expand div to max width when floatleft is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017880/expand-div-to-max-width-when-floatleft-is-set)
- [The magic of overflow hidden](http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/) (external)

However I can't manage to implement them in my case or they simply don't seem to work as I try to have a fix width on the right and a flexible width on the left (unlike the above examples).

Here is my problem (which is fairly simple) : I have a form with a search field (left) and a span element (right). The span element has a fixed width and height. I want the input to fit the remaining left space.

form :

```
<div id="container">
    <form>
        <input type="search" />
        <span class="submit"></span>
    </form>
</div>
```

style.css :

```
#container {
    width: 300px;
}

[type="search"] {

        /* Positionning
         * ------------ */
        display: block;
        height: 40px;
        padding: 0px 10px;
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    .submit {
        /* Positionning
         * ------------ */
        display: block;
        height: 40px;
        width: 50px;

        /* Styling
         * ------- */
        background-color: #CF0526;
    }
```

From what I've read, I thought that a `width: 100%; overflow: hidden` on the input and a `float: right` on the span who be enough, sadly not. Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SL3FB/) of my problem, hopefully it may help you.

EDIT: I changed the title from "left div" to "left input" as it may matter, especially since [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195836/2-column-div-layout-right-column-with-fixed-width-left-fluid) does not work while it looks accurate for divs positionning.

Comment: maybe this helps you: http://jsfiddle.net/SL3FB/7/

Comment: @caramba Thanks for your answer. I could achieve this result too but couldn't get further (aligned span and input).

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the property `calc` like this:

```
input[type="search"] {
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:30px;
  float:left;
}
.submit {
  float:left;
  width: 40px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

The demo http://jsfiddle.net/SL3FB/10/ ... Maybe a problem the [compatibility](http://caniuse.com/calc)

Another solution using `box.sizing` who has more [compatibility](http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing): http://jsfiddle.net/SL3FB/18/

Answer (score 1):

You can substract the width from the span to the width from the textfield which is 100%.

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SL3FB/15/.

Code is like this:

```
width:calc(100% - 50px);
float:left;
```

Make 'em both `float:left;` to have a better result!
Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use [CSS Tables](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#table-display)

1) Set `display: table-cell` for both the input and the span

2) Set a fixed width on the span and (the trick:) `width:100%` on the input

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/SL3FB/21/)**

```
#container {
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
form
{
    display:table;
    width: 100%;
}
.submit {
    display:table-cell;
    width: 40px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: red;
}
input
{
    width: 100%;
    display:table-cell;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

http://jsfiddle.net/SL3FB/4/

I've given your search a width of 85% so it fits up agains the red box.

```
.search {
    width:85%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I can't set a fixed width to the search container as the purpose of my problem is to have a flexible search bar.